# Map function with list parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a custom transform for a list of lists. I am trying to run arithmetic operations on the sublist, but I am not successful. Here is my code:

```
def my_transform(seq):
    new_seq = []
    new_seq[0] = seq[0] + 100
    new_seq[1] = seq[1] - 1
    new_seq[2] = seq[2] * seq[2]
    return new_seq

my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

new_list = map(my_transform, my_list) # error
# ideal output:
#[[101,1,9], [104,4,36]]
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
map(my_transform,my_list)
File "<pyshell#7>", line 3, in my_transform
new_seq[0] = seq[0] + 100
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I also tried:

```
[my_transform(L) for L in my_list]
```

That gave me the same error, too. How can I get the results using map and/or list comprehension? Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your function.

`new_seq[0]` tries to reference the first element of the list, but it's not there, so it gives the error. To fix this, we could make `new_seq` the length of the original list, or use `append`, but a much simpler solution would be to change the function so that it doesn't use an intermediate list at all.

```
def my_transform(seq):
    return [seq[0] + 100, seq[1] - 1, seq[2] * seq[2]]
```

If we try this function, we can see it works.

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> map(my_transform, my_list)
[[101, 1, 9], [104, 4, 36]]
```

Comment: Nice job pointing out there is no need for a new list like that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your new list starts out empty, which is why you get index errors trying to access items that don't exist, I've filled it with placeholder `0`s to remedy this:

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> def my_transform(seq):
        new_seq = [0] * len(seq)
        new_seq[0] = seq[0] + 100
        new_seq[1] = seq[1] - 1
        new_seq[2] = seq[2] * seq[2]
        return new_seq

>>> map(my_transform, my_list)
[[101, 1, 9], [104, 4, 36]]
```

Alternatively you can initialize to to a copy of `seq` like so:

```
new_seq = list(seq)
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because the element 0, 1 and 2 are not defiend, you can write

```
def my_transform(seq):
    new_seq = []
    new_seq.append(seq[0] + 100)
    new_seq.append(seq[1] - 1)
    new_seq.append(seq[2] * seq[2])
    return new_seq
```